# Encrypt TcpStream for Login Server - Necessary?

Tags: c#, encryption, authentication, client-server

I'm writing a C# .NET application that requires a secure Login. I've already got the necessary functionality to store passwords securely with a hash and salt in a database, however, I'm now moving from the testing phase. Before during development (the Login wasn't prioritized) I was just connecting to my database directly. I'm aware this is insecure for a production application as you blatantly store your database credentials in the code. Instead, I'm opting to create a simple Asynchronous TCP Socket server that listens for a username, sends the salt from the database back, then the client hashes the entered password (salt is stored locally temporarily) and sends that back to the server. The server then checks if they match; sends back true/false if the user checks out.

I've done some research and looked into encrypting the TCP Connection, however, is this *really necessary*, since the password will already be hashed? Or is there a better way of doing things in entirety? I'm open to suggestions on how the client/server architecture should work. The Login doesn't play *that* important of a role in the application as a whole, but it will be production grade and I do not want to put a poorly designed application out there.

Comment: What I'd recommend doing is sending the plain md5 hash to the server and hashing it server side, that way the salt is not exposed. Also, encryption isn't that necissary, but you don't want all of your data being visible over the wire!

Comment: @ChristianStewart Thanks for the suggestion. I was originally thinking about this, but then I'd have to change the registration mechanism, correct?

Comment: What is the authentication mechanism all about? What happens after the user has authenticated? Likely one authenticates to get access to information/resources not everybody has access to. Will you send those things non-encrpyted over the wire, too? It really depends on what you want to archive, there's no correct answer to your question.

Comment: I'm writing a Login server for a sort of collaboration application. That part of the application is pretty much a completely different thing. It has its own server and so on. The Login server basically handles registration and logging into the other part. Sorry that I wasn't clear on this.

Comment: Without *accurately* describing your protocol, it's difficult to tell what the attacks are, but it sounds insecure at first glance. **Do not roll your own authentication, do not pass go, do not collect $200.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> then the client hashes the entered password (salt is stored locally temporarily) and sends that back to the server. The server then **checks if they match**; sends back true/false if the user checks out.
>
> I've done some research and looked into encrypting the TCP Connection, however, is this really necessary, since the password will already be hashed?

It doesn't matter what you call a "password", the only thing that matters is what **the server** will accept as valid credentials. If you input a password and the server hashes it there (as @Christian Stewart suggested in the comments), then you password is your credential. If you salt and hash the password yourself, and send the result to the server, then **this result** will be your credential. Intercepting it is as good as intercepting the original password + salt.

So, yes, you must also encrypt your connection, before sending credentials through it. The [`SslStream` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx), seems to be the easiest way to do that (check the example code at the bottom, both for server and client), and it supports both server authentication and optionally client authentication as well (in case you also want to restrict which machines will have access to the Login server).

Comment: This is a desktop application, and I originally had it connecting directly to the database which I understood wasn't good practice for a production level application?

Comment: No, not good at all, since people can use the database user to wreak havok on your database... @user81572

Comment: Yeah @Christian Stewart, I have worked with databases in the past, but never a Login, only storing information as a persistence layer. This is an application just by me. Previously when I did something similar on a team I didn't actually touch any networking code.

Comment: @user81572 as I said in the second bullet point, you either store the credentials somewhere or the user inputs them. The second option is not common AFAIK for multi-user environments, since a single compromised user would expose the whole database, but can work for single user applications. I might be wrong in this, but I don't think there's anything wrong with saving password credentials in plain text files, as long as the OS does a good job of protecting them. Web systems do that routinely, dunno about desktop ones...

Comment: @mgibsonbr This is vastly different than a web system. If I was to save the database credentials to the local system someone keen enough on finding them could easily get the database user account and drop the table or get all my hashes/usernames/emails at least. As I said, during development as I wasn't really worried too much I just had a simple .NET SQL Connector straight into the database. If I did it locally it would defeat the purpose of having a Login server.

Comment: @user81572 I understand that, unfortunatly I don't have enough experience with Desktop systems to be of any help. Maybe [this question](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/20294/6939) on security.SE might give some additional hints... (the accepted answer touches the subject of a Login server, but does not give many details though - which seems to be your primary interest)

Comment: @mgibsonbr Thanks for the answer. He kind of said what I already knew. Back to the original question, I'm wondering if it is safe to submit "plain text" hashes over a TCP Socket.

Comment: @user81572 about that, see my updated answer. If your hash is "what the server will check" then the hash **is** the password, and as such you do need to protect it from eavesdroppers.

Comment: Thanks for the update @mgibsonbr ! I was originally thinking of doing what you were saying.. as I'm looking back I could probably change how it (registration) works. However, I think encryption is probably more worthwhile in the end looking at the rest of my project. Could you possibly give me a link or two to what I'd need to look into to encrypt the TCP socket connection? My server is a heavily modified version of the MSDN example for an Asynchronous server and my client isn't really oriented around networking at all. It currently would just open a simple Socket to the server.

Comment: @user81572 Using SSL should be the safest IMHO (covers both encryption and authentication). Check my updated answer. Judging from the example code, it shouldn't be hard to wrap your streams (from the socket connections) in `SslStream`s, keeping the rest of the code intact.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Thanks for your help. Marking your answer as the best because you pointed out that the server would use the original hash as the password and encryption would be necessary. You might want to consider revising your answer and removing the part involving IIS and web servers.

Answer (score 2):

1) If you are sending sensitive data, the easiest way to protect it is to use SSL.  If this is an internal project, you can generate your own certificate.  Also, talk to your IT staff about whether this is even a potential problem.  If this is going to be deployed in a properly-configured wired intranet situation, users can't see each other's traffic.

2) Your use of salts and hashes is messed up and it no longer solves the problem that it's meant to.  Hashing and salting is meant to render the contents of the database unhelpful for an attacker.  That's not the case here, since what is stored in the database is what's accepted by the server as an authentication token.  Hashing must be done on the server so that the value the server accepts over the wire is irreversibly (hash) and uniquely (salt) transformed into the value that appears in the user store.  Now it's true that an attacked can't reverse it to get the user's password (i.e. what they type in to your client) - which is good - but an attacker doesn't need the password if they know the value in the database.

3) Put on your attacker hat.  If you watched your authentication exchange take place, would you be able to log in without knowing the secret?  Yes, you would just send the last thing the client sent.  So this channel should be encrypted.

4) If you can avoid it, don't write your own crypto.  Don't even manage users if you can avoid it.  People don't want to manage users and groups in every application they use - and I say this as someone who's made this mistake before.  Can you use LDAP or domain authentication or something?

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to authenticate an user with the server without ever transmitting the password, using protocols such as the free [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_remote_password_protocol) used by World of Warcraft.

SRP will perform a serie of challenges to authenticate the user based on what each party knows about the password, without ever leaking sensitive information about it to the network.

Still using WoW as reference, there are open source emulators for it such as [TrinityCore](https://github.com/TrinityCore/TrinityCore/) that give you a solid exemple of SRP in action.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I've never really worked with anything like that so I don't know where I'd start.